# How can I do a rectangle rounded in HTML? Not CSS

Tags: html, email, outlook, signature

I'd like to create an outlook signature with this shape. How can I do it in HTML? It seems like outlook doesn't allow css.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dzAR.jpg)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

CSS capabilities are very limited in Outlook messages. The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup with CSS. You can find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

So, I'd recommend creating and using images instead.